# Transform the dataset using `data.table` syntax

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset in tidy-data format with columns as follows

> Time-AgentID-AC-Layer-Type-Data

For each `(Time, AgentID, AC, Layer, Type)`, there are `3` `Data` values; you can think of these data values are `x,y,z` coordinates.

And I want to transform this data set into something like

> Agent1_atT0-Agent2_atT0-...-Agent1_atT1-Agent2_atT2-...

where each rows are`x,y,z`

```
        Agent1_atT0    Agent2_atT0   ...   Agent1_atT1    Agent2_atT2

x        0.1               0.2    ...
y       ...
z        ...
```

How can I do this using the `data.table` syntax?

Here is a first 10 data points:

```
structure(list(Time = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), AgentID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AC = c("a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), Layer = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Type = c("w", "w", "w", "w", 
"w", "w", "w", "w", "w", "w"), Data = c(-0.0508897, 0.05661726, 
-0.38694093, -0.09898576, 0.0067616105, -0.44827247, 0.07630736, 
-0.072737664, 0.31485856, -0.34015945)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f83ee8108e0>, sorted = "Time")
```

Note that, for each column, there are multiple different possible values, so please don't say "but you have only 0s in `Time` column". This is just a part of the a huge dataset.

Comment: Are your 3 `Data` values ("like" x, y, z) inside a single `Data` column nested? Or spread out over separate rows? Would it be possible to share sample data to describe further (maybe with `dput()`)?

Comment: @Ben sure; see my edit.

Comment: Thank you --- and how are `AC` `Layer` and `Type` used in this case? Or are they ignored? Looks like you want the values (such as .1 and .2 in the example) from `Data`, and the column names `Agent1_T0`, `Agent2_T1` etc. from `Time` and `Agent` columns, is that correct?

Comment: @Ben Actually, it would be much better if we can incorportate them to the column names too, like "Agent1_T0_AC-c_L1_Type-w".

Comment: @Ben The `Type` and `AC` columns contain single characters only. `Layer` contains only non-negative integers

Comment: And how are `x` `y` `z` indicated in the raw data? Is it assumed that the data is in the format so the row 1 is `x`, 2 is `y`, 3 is `z`, 4 is `x`, 5 is `y`...etc.? Repeated?

Comment: @Ben No, whether the given data belongs to `x,y,z` is indicated on the `Type` column; classic tidy-data format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to consider - though I may be off (please let me know).

I created an example `data.table` for illustration that includes some of the columns mentioned:

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(42)

dt <- data.table(
  Time = c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3)),
  AgentID = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1),
  AC = "a",
  Type = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"),
  Data = runif(9)
)

   Time AgentID AC Type      Data
1:    0       1  a    x 0.9148060
2:    0       2  a    y 0.9370754
3:    0       1  a    z 0.2861395
4:    1       2  a    x 0.8304476
5:    1       1  a    y 0.6417455
6:    1       2  a    z 0.5190959
7:    2       1  a    x 0.7365883
8:    2       2  a    y 0.1346666
9:    2       1  a    z 0.6569923
```

By combining `paste` and `Map`, you can create a new `Key` column that includes the combination of column names and values (e.g., `Time_1`, `AgentID_2`, etc.) pasted together into one long string.

Then, you can use `dcast` to put into wide form:

```
dt[, Key := do.call(
  paste, c(Map(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = "_"), names(.SD), .SD), sep = "_")
  ), 
  .SDcols = setdiff(names(dt), "Data")][
    , c("Key", "Data", "Type")][
      , dcast(.SD, Type ~ Key, value.var = "Data")]
```

I used `setdiff` here is selecting columns to use in pasting columns with values; in this case, it will use all columns except for `Data`.

Giving this final result:

```
   Type Time_0_AgentID_1_AC_a_Type_x Time_0_AgentID_1_AC_a_Type_z Time_0_AgentID_2_AC_a_Type_y Time_1_AgentID_1_AC_a_Type_y
1:    x                     0.914806                           NA                           NA                           NA
2:    y                           NA                           NA                    0.9370754                    0.6417455
3:    z                           NA                    0.2861395                           NA                           NA
   Time_1_AgentID_2_AC_a_Type_x Time_1_AgentID_2_AC_a_Type_z Time_2_AgentID_1_AC_a_Type_x Time_2_AgentID_1_AC_a_Type_z
1:                    0.8304476                           NA                    0.7365883                           NA
2:                           NA                           NA                           NA                           NA
3:                           NA                    0.5190959                           NA                    0.6569923
   Time_2_AgentID_2_AC_a_Type_y
1:                           NA
2:                    0.1346666
3:                           NA
```

Comment: yes, this is the thing that I want to crease, but could you also share your exact code?I'm really not that much used to the `data.table` syntax.

Comment: oh, no problem :) I thought you've finished